Accessing Netdata behind Traefik reverse-proxy
On my ubuntu server, I have Traefik as reverse proxy server. Traefik runs in a docker container and it forwards connections to other services based on domain names, that are also running in docker containers. For each container I use a docker-compose.yml file.
Now everything works as expected, except service Netdata. Netdata is configured using network_mode: host, which means that netdata is directly connected to the host's port, in this case port 19999. What I tried to achieve is Traefik to forward the requests for netdata to the host's port on 19999. What happens is a "too many redirect" error.
Here's how my Traefik's docker-compose.yml looks like:
version: '3.9'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v3.0
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    expose:
      - 8080
    networks:
      - proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
      - ./log:/var/log
    command:
      - --log.level=INFO
      - --log.filepath=/var/log/traefik.log
      - --accesslog=true
      - --accesslog.filepath=/var/log/access.log

      - --api.dashboard=true

      - --providers.docker.network=proxy
      - --providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false

      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=websecure
      - --entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https

      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.websecure.asDefault=true
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.certresolver=tlsresolver

      - --certificatesresolvers.tlsresolver.acme.email=my-fake@gmail.com
      - --certificatesresolvers.tlsresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.tlsresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json
 labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      # dashboard
      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`dashboard.mycoolwebapp.io`)
      - traefik.http.services.dashboard.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=api@internal
      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.middlewares=api-auth
      - traefik.http.middlewares.api-auth.basicauth.users=xxxx:$$apr1$$xxxxx$xxxxxxxxxx/
      # netdata
      - traefik.http.routers.netdata.rule=Host(`netdata.mycoolwebapp.io`)
      - traefik.http.routers.netdata.service=netdata
      - traefik.http.services.netdata.loadbalancer.server.port=19999

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
    name: proxy

My Netdata's docker-compose.yml is very basic:
version: '3'
services:
  netdata:
    image: netdata/netdata
    container_name: netdata
    pid: host
    network_mode: host
    restart: unless-stopped
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
      - SYS_ADMIN
    security_opt:
      - apparmor:unconfined
    volumes:
      - ./netdataconfig:/etc/netdata
      - netdatalib:/var/lib/netdata
      - netdatacache:/var/cache/netdata
      - /etc/passwd:/host/etc/passwd:ro
      - /etc/group:/host/etc/group:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /etc/os-release:/host/etc/os-release:ro
      - /var/log:/host/var/log:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /run/dbus:/run/dbus:ro

volumes:
  netdatalib:
  netdatacache:

My idea is to have Traefik forward the requests to localhost on port 19999 of the host (the server).
But it seems not to work, it somehow causes too many requests.
I hope you guys can see the problem, but I'm a bit stuck on here.

When using labels for Traefik Docker configuration discovery, they always need to be placed on the target container, as that will be the target container that Traefik will proxy/forward requests to.
If labels on the netdata service/container don’t work, because it is using host networking, then I would try a dynamic config file, which can use any target IP and is loaded by providers.file in static config (example).
